# Using RabbitMQ with nServiceBus (for C#) vs using Amazon SQS

Tags: c#, message-queue, nservicebus, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

If I understand correctly, I can use nServiceBus as a "framework" and / or a wrapper around RabbitMQ
My preference of RabbitMQ is being able to use it on linux machines

**Background**

I have an application that enables people to upload images.
These images will require thumbnails.

Our application is predominantly asp.net (c#)

My idea is to do the following:

- upload the full size images to S3 (or whatever storage service)
- create a "message" that has input storage key, output storage key, width, height - and add to queue.
- there will be a linux server acting as a worker (windows licensing constraint) that reads the messages from the queue, and does the actual resizing
- new image will be placed on S3, defined by output key of received message

I could use Amazon SQS i suppose, but I wanted to explore the possibility of nServiceBus with RabbitMQ for transport.

Does anyone have any further info on doing this?
I saw this on GitHub: http://github.com/machine/machine.mta/tree/master/Source/NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.RabbitMQ but was wondering how this could be used?

What would your preferred way of approaching this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex, I use SQS very often, but there are other services that could be useful for you.
You may Google 'Cloud Message Queue' and find plenty of those.

Answer (score 0):

`<shameless_plug>` You might want to look at [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com) too. It's written specifically as a .NET API for RabbitMQ. It works fine on Mono too.

Comment: Please note you should be careful about presenting your own project as an answer if the user has not explicitly asked for recommendations (and such questions end up getting closed/deleted nowadays when they are found, anyway). In this case, the OP was asking about how to use a specific API he had already found.

Answer (score -2):

May be this [project](http://github.com/machine/machine.mta) can give your idea where to look further